# TNotebook borderwidth not working for some reason

Tags: python, tkinter, border

I have problems with a Tkinter Notebook styling. I'm trying to remove the border width but somehow it doesn't seem to work passing it to the style object. Does anyone know what could be the problem here?

```
    self.tab_style = ttk.Style()
    self.tab_style.theme_use("clam")
    self.tab_style.configure('TNotebook.Tab', borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
    self.tab_style.configure('TNotebook', borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
    self.tab_style.layout('TNotebook.Tab', [])
    self.tab_control = ttk.Notebook(root, style='TNotebook')
```

Comment: According to [tkdoc](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_notebook.htm#M38), `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` are not the available style options.

Comment: do you know if there is a workaround for this? I need to set borderwidth to 0 in order to not bring up some bugs on mac